# PHP - Trying to delete some elements of an array then repost all the content to a file.

Tags: php, arrays

```
if(isset($_POST["delete"])){
    $file_name = 'ids';
    touch($file_name);
    $handle = fopen($file_name, 'r+');
    $stream = file_get_contents('ids');
    $pieces = explode(" ", $stream);
    unset($pieces[0]);
    unset($pieces[1]);
    unset($pieces[2]);
    file_put_contents("ids", "\n" );
    file_put_contents("ids", $pieces);
    fclose($handle);
  }
```

So I'm sure this is wicked messy and a terrible way to accomplish my goal but I am learning PHP for school and this is giving me a lot of issues.

When I press my button I want to take the content I have in 'ids', change it by deleting the strings located in the array at 0,1,2 and then rewrite the new content to 'ids'. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this broken code or do you just want to optimize it?  What are we solving here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where you are getting stuck, but I would guess it is regarding the "re-assembly" process, so I'll fix that.

Untested Code:

```
if(isset($_POST["delete"])){
    $file_name='ids';
    touch($file_name);
    $handle=fopen($file_name, 'r+');
    $stream=file_get_contents($file_name);
    $content=str_replace(" ","\n",explode(" ", $stream,4)[3]); // explode into a max of 4 elements, access the last element, replace spaces with `\n`
    file_put_contents($file_name,$content);
    fclose($handle);
}
```